# Displaying only relevant data in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to allow an employee to fill out a timesheet but they may only select projects which they are assigned to, I tried a few different things but can't seem to get anything close to working.

In time sheet index

```
<div class="field">
     <%= f.label :Project %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :project_id, @skills, :id, :projectName, :prompt => "Select Project" %>
  </div>
```

time_sheet controller

```
 def index
    @time_sheets = TimeSheet.all
    @skills = @current_employee.project.all

    @time_sheet = TimeSheet.new
    @sheet_day = current_employee.time_sheets.group_by(&:date)
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) :Date.today
    @today = params[:date] || Date.today
  end
```

I've looked around and I'm still unsure how to approach this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is a group of projects named `@skills`?

Comment: The label should be `<%= f.label :project_ids, "Projects" %>` otherwise the FOR attibute will not match the name of the input - very bad for accessibility.

Comment: @max was just giving it as a name so I could test if it worked, I have a link table employee_projects which stores the records I want to display if they have the current users id?

Comment: If you have setup the associations correctly `current_employee.projects` (you're using the wrong pluralization for the name of the association) should give you that. But there are not enough details in the question for anybody to be able to know. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve